# develop Webconference using an existing open source or from scratch

Tags: web-applications, open-source, conferencing

I'm developing a web conference application . Is is for the best of time and performance to use an existing open source webconference and ad some fonctionnalities or start it from scratch ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That really depends on what you want your application to do.

E.g. Whether existing opensource applications / libraries meet the requirements for your application.

As you haven't specified what time or performance constrains or other requirements for your application are it is difficult to make a recommendation due to lack of information.

If you do decide to use existing Open Source libraries or software, I suggest you have a look at 
the following projects, even if it is just to give yourself a better idea of your application's requirements.

- [openmeetings](http://code.google.com/p/openmeetings/)
- [bigbluebutton](http://www.bigbluebutton.org/)
- [webhuddle](https://www.webhuddle.com/)
- [Ekiga](http://ekiga.org/)
- [vmukti](http://code.google.com/p/vmukti/)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick reply.the time constraint is (4 to 5 months).this application will etablish a audio/video conversation with many persons.I know that all the open source apps have those fonctionalities which why I wanted to work with.but as this being my graduate assignement I need to add some new fonctions that are related to the compagny activity domain which BI.

Comment: I suggest you add additional information to your question by editing it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at WebRTC. Maybe it makes sense to use that for a graduate assignement.